# StreamReader doesn't send data always

Tags: c#, .net, webserver

Below is the code and we want to send data from the response. But the **issue** is that it doesn't always send the data.

**Code**

```
 var rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                            var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);


                            var context = _listener.GetContext();
                            var request = context.Request;
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                request.ContentEncoding))
                            {
                                var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                Console.WriteLine("Messages ************");
                                Console.WriteLine(text);
                                AiMessagePublisher.SendMessages(text);
                            }
```

Sometimes it doesn't come to `Console.WriteLine("Messages ************");`

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: sometimes it doesn't come to Console.WriteLine("Messages ************");

Comment: @GulMdErshad what *is* the input? is it actually text? (there's no reason to *assume* it is text) - is it throwing an exception, perhaps?

Comment: @Marc Gravell, if I trigger twice then first time it doesn't send but second time it sends. Its stream of XML. It doesn't throw exception.

Comment: It is strange that first time it doesn't come to this line using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                request.ContentEncoding)). But, second time it comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using below code:

```
 var context = _listener.GetContext();
                        try
                        {


                            var request = context.Request;
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                request.ContentEncoding))
                            {
                                var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                Console.WriteLine("Messages ************");
                                Console.WriteLine(text);
                                publisher.SendMessages(text);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                        finally
                        {

                            context.Request.InputStream.Close();

                        }
```